# React webpage lagging with three fiber model (on chrome)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-chrome, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm fairly new to react, and building a react webpage (to document an electric conversion of a triumph spitfire convertible). On the webpage I've included a 3D CAD file of the car that's interactable using react three fiber.

Unfortunately, the scrolling on the website (especially when viewing the first image on the landing page- not the three fiber file itself) is **extremely** laggy. The scrolling does not seem to be an issue on firefox or mobile.

The website (still largely under construction) is hosted on firebase and can be found here:
https://electric-spitfire-website.web.app/

Again, I'm fairly new, and I'm sure some of this is a terrible way to have built much of the website. Any advice would be massively appreciated...

The .js code for my 'Landing Page' is this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, lazy } from 'react';
import {useGLTF, Stage, PresentationControls} from "@react-three/drei";
import MenuBanner from '../MenuBanner'; // Import the MenuBanner component
import Glass_Spit_Model from './Glass_Spit_Model'; // Import the 3D Glass Spitfire component
import './Landing_Page.css';
import Spitfire_Team_Bridge_Photo from '../Photos/Spitfire_Team_Bridge_Photo.jpg'; 
 
const Spitfire_Bridge_Width = 5800 //pixels
const Spitfire_Bridge_Height = 3800 //pixels


function Landing_Page() {

  const appRef = useRef(null);
  const [backgroundHeight, setBackgroundHeight] = useState(0);

  const viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
  const ScalingFactor = viewportWidth/Spitfire_Bridge_Width;
  const imageheight = Spitfire_Bridge_Height * ScalingFactor;

  useEffect(() => {
    setBackgroundHeight(imageheight);
  }, []);

  return (

    <div className="App">
       <MenuBanner />
      <div className="App" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${Spitfire_Team_Bridge_Photo})`,     height: `${backgroundHeight}px` }}>
        <header className="App-header" style={{ height: `${backgroundHeight}px` }}>
          <p>
            Welcome to the website for the Electric Spitfire!
          </p>
        </header>
      </div>
      <div className="Landing-page-buffer" style={{ height: `${backgroundHeight/2.25}px` }}></div>
      <Glass_Spit_Model style={{ height: `${800}px` }}/>
    </div>
    
  );
}


export default Landing_Page;
}
```

The "Glass Spit Model" is the 3D CAD file in question (Named this way because the CAD spitfire is see-through like glass). The "Menu Banner" is the navigation menu that can be seen on the top of the website.

In the first part of this "landing page" file, I do a bit of math with the width and height of the background image to try and set the image to fill the width (and maintain it's proportional height) of different computer/mobile screen sizes.

The "landing-page-buffer" is just a black flex box to provide some space between the first background image and the three fiber CAD file.

The Glass_Spit_Model.js looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../index';
import './Glass_Spit_Model.css';
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei';
import { Model } from '../Models/Glass_Spitfire';
 
function Glass_Spit_Model(){


return(
    <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
        <Canvas
            colorManagement
                shadowMap // highlight-line
                camera={{ position: [-3, 2, 5], fov: 90 }}>
            <directionalLight
                intensity={0.5}
                castShadow // highlight-line
                shadow-mapSize-height={512}
                shadow-mapSize-width={512}/>
            <OrbitControls />
            <Suspense fallback={null}>
                <Model/>
            </Suspense>
        </Canvas></div>
);


}

export default Glass_Spit_Model;`
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advice, I really appreciate it.